# Spring Integration - IBM MQ - Consuming large messages from Queue

Tags: ibm-mq, spring-integration

We are using spring integration to connect to IBM MQ V7.5 to read messages from queue. We occasionally get large messages to read. SI jms adapter fails to read to large message, but it works for smaller messages. Below is the exception we are getting

```
23:18:35,470  WARN DefaultMessageListenerContainer:839 - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'queue:///Cis.Orders' - trying to recover. Cause:
JMSWMQ2002: Failed to get a message from destination 'XXX'.; 
nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '1' ('MQCC_WARNING') reason '2080' ('MQRC_TRUNCATED_MSG_FAILED').
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedMessageEOFException: JMSWMQ2002: Failed to get a message from destination 'Cis.Orders'.
WebSphere MQ classes for JMS attempted to perform an MQGET; however WebSphere MQ reported an error.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error.
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:524)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:216)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:124)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.getMsg(WMQConsumerShadow.java:1376)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSyncConsumerShadow.receiveInternal(WMQSyncConsumerShadow.java:227)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.receive(WMQConsumerShadow.java:1109)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.receive(WMQMessageConsumer.java:460)
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl.receiveInboundMessage(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:766)
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl.receive(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:474)
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageConsumer.receive(MQMessageConsumer.java:212)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveMessage(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:430)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:310)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1102)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1094)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:991)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '1' ('MQCC_WARNING') reason '2080' ('MQRC_TRUNCATED_MSG_FAILED').
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:204)
... 15 more
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: "...('MQCC_WARNING') reason '2080' ('MQRC_TRUNCATED_MSG_FAILED')..." from near the top of your exception trace suggests that either one component in the system has a maximum length that your really long messages exceed, or that your really long messages take so long to transmit that something times out the connection before the transfer is complete and then fails to process the partial message.  I'd suggest looking for maximum message size or time out periods in the configuration for your components.

Comment: Thanks Artem, I increased receive-timeout on jms channel and still the same error, I suspect MQGET sends a default buffersize of 4MB and if the message is > 4MB, spring default listener should catch this exception and do another MQGET setting buffer size data length. Not sure my theory is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The application buffer looks to be too small for your message. 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21167205

Answer (score 0):

The JMS client shouldn't ever return MQRC_TRUNCATED_MSG_FAILED, as you don't have any physical control over the buffer sizes in use, and this error indicates the receive buffer was too small to receive the message.

It's difficult to tell without the full exception stack, and without knowing your current version, but you could try upgrading to 7.5.0.3, the newest MQ 7.5 fix pack.

Or you could open a PMR with IBM support to investigate.

Comment: Thanks Tim, We are using spring integration ver 4, MQ 7.5 and MQ 8 client jars. As you said we don't have control of passing buffer size through spring integration. I can read the message using talend job, so that suggest MQ Server setttings are correct , I checked MaxMsgLen, everything is setup correctly.

Comment: But what version of MQ are you using exactly? Do you mean 7.5 queue manager and 8.0 client? What exact versions? 7.5.0.3 and 8.0.0.0?